# DataGridView NoOfVisibleRowsChanged event or any other idea?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have this method which does certain checks and applies a color code on the datagridview rows making certain rows Red, some Blue etc.
Lets call it ImposeColorGrouping().

When I filter columns and redraw (this is done) the datagridview, the coloring of rows is lost.

I am looking for an event to invoke the ImposeColorGrouping() method.

I tried Paint event, but that makes other controls on screen unstable (doesn't draw some them at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color of each row during the RowsAdded event.

Comment: Spot on!! Exactly what I was looking for. Works great when I put ImposeColorGrouping() inside dataGridView_RowsAdded event method. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to clarify that RowsAdded may be raised for every single row that is added. So if ImposeColorGrouping() is coloring ALL the rows, you may start to run into performance problems as the number of rows increases. You should try to color just the row being added.